# Objects auto-deleted from Activity instance?

Tags: java, android

I have a single activity application where `MainActivity` takes care of changing between different fragments.

`FirstFragment`collects sensor data, and at the end stores this in `MainAcitvity`via `((MainActivity)getActivity()).setValues(values);`

`SecondFragment` presents some items in a RecyclerView (not important for this case), one of these are a button to open `ThirdFragment`. In this Fragment the list of objects is still alive as I can see by `Log.i(TAG, ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getValues().toString());`

`ThirdFragment`offers the possibility to write some comments and save these alongside the sensor data found in `((MainActivity)getActivity).getValues();` for persistent storage (InternalStorage serialization + SQL row with reference to filename).

Problem is, by the time we are in `ThirdFragment`, MainActivity's list of objects are completely gone. I've spent some time debugging this, and I cannot see where these objects are deleted. Also, this is a new problem, and I cannot see that any of my new adjustments to the code should affect MainActivity's list.

**This has lead me to believe that there may be some functionality in the Android OS that automatically deletes old objects? Could this be the case?** If so, I would be better off persistently storing the data in `MainActivity` and bring it back from storage in `ThirdFragment`.

From `MainActivity`

```
public ArrayList<GsrConverted> getValues() {
    return values;
}

public void setValues(ArrayList<GsrConverted> values) {
    this.values = values;
    Log.i(TAG, "Values were set");
}

public void removeValues() {
    values.clear();
    Log.i(TAG, "Values removed");
}
```

These are only called as designed, they are not called in-between `SecondFragment`and `ThirdFragment`

Comment: *I would be better off persistently storing the data in MainActivity* activities are not for storing data. If you need persistance just use a database of some sort

Comment: Yes you are right, but are objects auto deleted to save memory? And if so, is there a way I can check if that indeed is the case here?

Comment: no they are not. It depends on the context of the variables. Show us what setValues does

Comment: As long as an object has an active handle "pointing" to it, it is never destroyed. When it can no longer be "grabbed" by any existing handle, it is a candidate to deletion via the process called garbage collection. This process is automatically launched by the system from time to time, and it is not possible to predict when it will be executed. You can nevertheless ask for it's execution with the function `gc.

Comment: Thank you for your comments both of you! I do not know for sure what happened here, but I suspect the garbage collection. I followed Tim's advice and persistently stored the data instead of trying to keep object references alive. Now it's back to normal :)